# What are Adventurer's Journals for?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've stacked already 5 of these Adventurer's Journal's, but I can't seem to figure out what for are they used in RoS. Seems odd, that there can be some item in the game, that has no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Adventurer's Journal used to be a crafting material for the Pender's Purchase legendary item, but it was no longer made a required crafting material with patch 2.0.6.  More information [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Adventurer%27s_Journal).

Comment: So they have no prupose exepct selling them

Comment: Selling them for 50.000 gold is their new purpose.